# How to enable mysql binary logging in mac book

Tags: mysql, macos

I am using mac os catalina 10.15.4 .I am trying to enable binary logging in mysql by editing my.cnf file under [mysqld] section 
by using following configurations

```
log-bin=bin.log  // this line doesn't lets the mysql restart
log-bin-index=bin-log.index
max_binlog_size=100M
binlog_format=row
socket=mysql.sock
```

But when I am trying to restart mysql it throws error

> The server quit without updating PID file
>   How to do this ? ,any help or any link will be appreciated .

Comment: give it  path to a valid directory `log-bin = /usr/local/var/mysql/binlog`

Comment: should I have to create a folder binlog?@RiggsFolly

Comment: I think `binlog` is supposed to be the file name

Comment: still not working :( @RiggsFolly

Comment: then try `/var/log/binlog.log`

Comment: Still not working ,if i remove this line or comment it out then it works properly

Comment: I worked thanks :)